# What is a word or phrase similar to "sold out" that I can use for a free event which requires prior registration?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The context that I intended to use the phrase was along the lines of:

> The registration page no longer works because the workshop is [insert the phrase or word here].

The workshop was free so I was not sure if "sold out" was correct. Is there something else I can use?

Comment: Perhaps "full" or "closed to further registration" would work well.

Comment: @Graffito that is an answer. "The registration page is *no longer available* because the workshop is **fully booked**."

Comment: FWIW I have heard “sold out” used nonliterally for free tickets.

Comment: Another option is "at capacity," meaning that there is no room for additional participants.

Answer (score 4):

*The registration page no longer works because the workshop is **filled**.*

Here’s an example at [University of Montana Summer Conducting Workshop](https://www.umt.edu/music/festivals-and-camps/conducting-workshop/):

> *Registration for Conducting Workshop participants will be limited to 25. Applications will be accepted until the workshop is filled.*

It’s bad form, though, to defend a broken page. You should hide the registration form and note that the workshop is filled.

Comment: And for those of use who were absolutely convinced that this should either have been *"... has been filled"* or *"... is full"* rather than *"is filled"*, [Thesaurus entry here](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/filled) gives the example "The house was filled with laughter", and I find "the house is filled with laughter" just as acceptable, so "workshop is filled" must be acceptable, too. TL;DR +1!

Answer (score 1):

The workshop is ***fully booked***. (Each person who registered to attend *booked* their place.)

See senses 1 and 3 [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/book#Verb).

(The user WeatherVane had earlier suggested "fully booked" in a comment to the question.)

Comment: The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fully-booked) entry for the string 'fully booked' is more explicit. It's an idiom; one can't use say 'fully reserved', though the verbs 'book' and 'reserve' overlap quite considerably.